# Default constructor in mybatis with a complex parameter

Tags: java, constructor, mybatis

Let say that we have the following class:

```
public final class PersonDso {

    public final PersonDto personDto;

    public PersonDso(final Person personDto) {
        this.personDto = personDto;
    }

    public String getName(){return personDto.getName()}; 
    public String getEmail(){return personDto.getEmail()};
```

}

The PersonDto class has much more fields than name and email.

So, I created the following Mapper in mybatis:

```
<mapper namespace="my.package.domain.PersonDataMapper">

    <resultMap id="personDsoMap" type="my.package.dso.PersonDso">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="person" javaType="my.package.dto.PersonDTO"/>
        </constructor>
        <id column="p_id"/>
        <association property="personDto" columnPrefix="p_" resultMap="my.package.mapper.PersonMapper.BaseResultMap"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getPersons" resultMap="personDsoMap">
        select <includeColumns tableAlias="p" columnPrefix="p_" refid="my.package.mapper.PersonMapper.Base_Column_List"/>
        from PERSON p
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Basically is the following. From the query I can retrieve the PersonDto, but I do not want to expose my Dto to the outside, that's why I created the PersonDso. The personDso has a field personDto and I want MyBatis to create the PersonDso by passing the PersonDto to the constructor.

With this code, MyBatis is complaining with this:

```
Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property null
```

Answer (score 0):

The *javaType* attribute is important to choose which constructor (based on declared parameters types).

The error is raised because no query result column is mapped in the constructor arg. The column *person* does not exist.

Just set a mapping with a *resultMap* attribute in *arg* tag:

```
<resultMap type="PersonDto" id="personDtoMap">
    <!-- column to property mapping if not implicit matching -->
</resultMap>

<resultMap type="PersonDso" id="personDsoMap">
    <constructor>
      <arg resultMap="personDtoMap" javaType="PersonDto"/>
    </constructor>
    <id column="p_id" property="id"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getPersons" resultMap="personDsoMap"> [...] </select>
```

The association is then futile.